# Install Ubuntu with other linux distributions on same machine

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, bootloader

I have brand new machine. 
I want to install Ubuntu and one more Linux distributions on same machine. When the machine is up I want to have the option to choose which Linux to load.

Is it possible? 
How to do it?

Comment: Learn to spell "Ubuntu" first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Partition the hard drive into however many installations you want using a tool like GParted.
2. Install each distro into their respective partitions.
3. Install grub to the root of the hard drive. You can either

   - install Ubuntu last because it can automatically install grub to the root without issue, or
   - if you installed Ubuntu first you may need to re-install Grub for it, e. g. with the help of [Boot-Repair](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

There are many tutorials online to achieve exactly what you are attempting to do. That is my reason for not providing extreme detail and posting this to the community wiki, rather than to myself.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you are trying to accomplish you might be interested in looking at Oracle VirtualBox. With this you could:

1. Install Ubuntu
2. Boot into Ubuntu
3. Install VirtualBox
4. Install other Linux OS or other OS to run in Virtual Box (You could have multiple)
5. Boot the desired virtual machine from Virtual Box

This lets you run multiple "Virtual" computers inside your physical Ubuntu Machine. So you could have Ubuntu running, Linux Mint running and CentOS, all at the same time and be able to switch back and forth, copy across machines, etc...

This may not be exactly what you were after, but I thought I would contribute just in case this may be of interest to you.

Hope this helps.